# Has the expression "powered by", as used in website or softwares, a positive connotation?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

This question is a spin-off of [this one](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/how-would-powered-by-be-translated) in Portuguese SE. In that question, the OP wanted to know how to translate to Portuguese the expression *powered by* as used in websites or softwares when another company provides part of its functionality.

Personally, as a foreigner learning English, *powered by* seems to me as a *positive* way to say that, for instance, company XYZ is providing web hosting or the search engine for my website. It sounds to me like the website is *proud* to have such company offer me it's services.

I would like to know if native English speakers feel the same way or *powered by* sounds like a neutral way to say the same thing.

Comment: it sounds positive to my ear.

Comment: Yes. If they weren't proud of the fact that they are using XYZ they wouldn't advertise it by placing a "powered by" notification on their site.

Comment: The Challenger Tank is *powered by* a 12 cylinder, 1,200 horsepower diesel engine. That sounds quite positive to me.

Comment: The people who use it in describing websites (always their own websites, interestingly) certainly **think** that it has a positive connotation. In fact, it connotes an attempt at salesmanship more than any positive connotation. If you admire salesmanship, that's positive; if not, not. Because there is, in fact, no power involved, except 220 VAC in most cases.

Comment: Just a note- in India, 'powered by' means the same as the American 'presented by' (referring to TV sponsors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that XYZ Corporation is a giant of its kind, to say that your website, or whatever, is powered by it is a sutle way to add value to that product and enhance its earnings potential.

The same applies to reviewed by, supported by or recommended by, in different contexts.

Comment: Would it sound neutral if it was said _provided by_ instead of _powered by_?

Comment: @gmauch The moment you specify a brand name, either you want to advertise that brand or to enhance your product potentials.

Comment: At the same time, let's not forget that sometimes such statements are requested or even demanded by XYZ.